# Expansion of $z^3 \log ( (z-a)/(z-b))$ in $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some hints to evaluate the expansion of $z^3 \log((z-a)/(z-b))$ in $\infty$. I thougt that evaluating $\log(\frac 1 z -a)$ in $z = 0$ may be helpful. How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\frac{1}{z}$ then

$$z^3 \log ( (z-a)/(z-b))=\frac{1}{u^3}\left(\log(1-au)-\log(1-bu)\right)=\frac{1}{u^3}(-u(a-b)-\frac{u^2}{2}(a^2-b^2)-\frac{u^3}{3}(a^3-b^3)+o(u^3))$$ 
hence we find

$$z^3 \log ( (z-a)/(z-b))=-z^2(a-b)-\frac{z}{2}(a^2-b^2)-\frac{1}{3}(a^3-b^3)+o(1)$$

Comment: Nice :) Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.